# How to install librtaudio4 on Kubuntu-18.04.1?

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, dependencies

I'm trying to run my application on Kubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.

But when I run it I get the following error:

> librtaudio.so.4v5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

And if I run `sudo apt-get install librtaudio4`, it says:

> E: Unable to locate package librtaudio4

It seems that I can only install `librtaudio6` on Kubuntu 18.04.1. But my application is looking for `librtaudio4`.

In my case, What can I do to make my app work on Kubuntu 18.04.1?

Comment: Is this an app you yourself wrote, or an app written by someone else that you just need to use?

Comment: My app is written using openFrameworks which is C++ frameworks for multimedia purpose.

Comment: Then you need to see if there's an updated framework version that uses the newer version of `librtaudio` that's in 18.04.  Otherwise, it's not going to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any problems install this package from older Ubuntu version ([14.04 LTS in current case](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=librtaudio4)) manually:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rtaudio/librtaudio4_4.0.12~ds0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./librtaudio4_4.0.12~ds0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Note: usually this method is not recommended, but while using it you do not need to recompile/rewrite source code of your application.